# How to check if text contains words starting with '#' in django?

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to implement tags function on my blog application.

How can I check if 'text' of a post contains words starting with '#' and if yes make them urls redirecting to /tags/~word~?

so f.e. user can write a post 'I've been to #ny today and it was cool #yolo #summer' so it will create #ny, #yolo, #summer tags and make it an url redirecting to /tags/ny/, /tags/yolo/, and /tags/summer/,

I'm learning python and django only for like a week or two, theres probably some function I'm not aware of :)

Comment: You may also want to check the 'taggit' package: http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Sorry @obi, I'm deleting my answer because it's actually a bad idea, you shouldn't put raw HTML in a string like that (Django will even try to stop you in your template). Someone else who knows Django better will have to answer.

Comment: Using a template_tag and a regular expression.

Comment: Make sure to *first* clean up the text (escape potentially dangerous chars) and *then* add your HTML. Because you will need to mark it as safe with `mark_safe()`, and for that, it actually should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `#tags` with `<a href="/tag/links">links</a>` is the easier part

```
>>> import re
>>> t = 'Some #cool text here #whatya think!'
>>> re.sub(r'#(\w+)', r'<a href="/tag/\1">\1</a>', t)
'Some <a href="/tag/cool">cool</a> text here <a href="/tag/whatya">whatya</a> think!'
```

What's more important is to make it safe.

You could use a Template Tag so that you can easily call it like `{% link_tags t %}` in your template. But you need to filter or escape the raw HTML before adding your own. Don't use `mark_safe()` on an unfiltered string that came from a user! Ever.

Comment: I've created new filter: `@register.filter(name='hash')
def hash(text):
    return re.sub(r'#(\w+)', r'<a href="/tags/\1">#\1</a>', text)` and in templates: `{{ post.text|hash|linebreaks }}` The problem is that output on page is raw html values so it looks like `<a href="/tags/xxx">#xxx</a>` instead of being just #xxx with a link to tag. I could add `|safe` tag to templates but that will let users use other html codes. How could i fix that?